# Manually increment or decrement file reference counter (refcount) used by MSI installers?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, count, uninstallation

My understanding is that MSI installers use a file reference count to keep track of how many 'installers' installed a shared file (say a dll).
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\SharedDLLs

This way, say 3 products all install the same DLL, the refcount is at 3. When you run the uninstaller for one of the products, the uninstaller reduces the refcount to 2, but does not actually remove the file.

I am using a non-standard installer that will drop in a couple of files that are also installed by a regular installer. I was wondering if there is an easy way to programatically increment/decrement the file counter for those files? Is there a Windows SDK to do this?

This article talks about the concept but doesn't go into detail of how to implement it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954376.aspx

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be easier just to drop your DLL next to your executable, and run it side-by-side?  Then you wouldn't have to worry about versioning at all.

Comment: My 'installer' is a subset of the MSI installer and they both actually install to the same location...

Comment: Seems pretty simple to do a Registry value read, and if it exists then increase the value by one and write it back, and if it doesn't then create the item with a value of 1. But I agree with @Robert Harvey -- as much as you can avoid [DLL hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell), you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

The method you describe ("SharedDLLs" Registry key) has been deprecated and replaced by side-by-side assemblies, Microsoft's solution to "DLL hell".

Consider using a SxS assembly:
[Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367757.aspx)